# How to export 25 billion Elastic Security events?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm working as an MSSP off-boarding a client with 25 billion events. Every event needs to be backed up for compliance, I can query the indices and extract the JSON for each event via the Python API, but the script I'm using would take an absurd amount of time. Is there a better way to do this? Currently I'm just using a quick-and-dirty script to authenticate, query the information, store it persistently than query again. If it time's out I intend to rerun the script with searchAfter and this will be wrapped in a bash script eventually. Also searchAfter doesn't work, but I can fix that later if I go down this route. Also apologies for the messy code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import sys
import time

username = "USER"
password = "REDACTED"

elasticsearchEndpoint = "https://elastic.com:9243"

es = Elasticsearch(
    elasticsearchEndpoint, 
    basic_auth=(username, password), 
    request_timeout=120
)

SAI = "searchAfterIndex.txt"
file_path = "dump.out"
options = ["/rr", "rerun", "rr", "-rr", "--rr", "--rerun", "/rerun", "-rerun"]


query = {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "gte": "now-1y",
                        "lt": "now"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "must": [],
        "must_not": [],
        "should": []
    }
}

def getEvents(searchAfter=None):

    while True:
        if searchAfter is None:
            classVar = es.search(expand_wildcards='all', index="*-abc**", size=10000, sort="@timestamp:asc", query=query) # IDK if I need query=query
        else:
            time.sleep(.025)
            classVar = es.search(expand_wildcards='all', index="*-abc**", size=10000, search_after=searchAfter, sort="@timestamp:asc", query=query)
        
        hits = classVar.get("hits", {}).get("hits", [])

        with open(file_path, "a") as fp:
            for hit in hits:
                fp.write(str(hit))

        # Break condition
        if len(hits) == 10000:
            searchAfter = hits[-1]["sort"]
            with open(SAI, "w") as fp:
                fp.write(str(searchAfter).strip("[]"))
        else:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv)>=2 and sys.argv[1] in options:
        try:
            searchAfterIndex = open(SAI, "r").read()
            getEvents(searchAfterIndex)
            print("Done!", file=sys.stderr)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}", file=sys.stderr)

    try:
        getEvents()
        print("Done!", file=sys.stderr)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}", file=sys.stderr)
```

I tried exporting via share feature in Discover tab, but this often times out and errors
I tried exporting via API, but this takes a long time

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to solve this issue:

1. you can improve performance of your script by running it in [PIT context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) and sorting on `_shard_doc` instead of timestamp (by the way sorting on timestamp might skip records with the same timestamp)
2. you can give up on your script and use one of existing json dump utilities such as elasticdump.
3. instead of dumping all records as json, you can create a snapshot of the entire index and store the snapshots. Since this is for compliance nobody will most likely look at it anyway, and if they will they can always install elasticsearch again and [search these snapshots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/searchable-snapshots.html). It will be slow, but not as slow as grepping through json dumps.

Comment: option 3 is i.m.h.o the best. Create a backup snapshot and give the customer the files or store it directly in their cloud storage/filesystem. All they have to do when restoring is create a new deployment and register the location as repository.

Comment: That's what I would have done. But since they are migrating off elasticsearch, maybe they don't want to have anything to do with it, so I offered other alternatives :)